# Alternatives to Windows DFS (distributed file system)

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

The Win 2008 dedicated server we're leasing doesn't have Win DFS installed (and we'd have to upgrade our hosting contract to get it). Are there any alternatives available that we could install so we can add some redundancy to the data to improve availablility?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try [OpenAFS](http://www.openafs.org/).